# pattens in regexNER in core-nlp

Tags: regex, named-entity-recognition, stanford-nlp

I would like to have a regex pattenr for regexner inside the core-nlp pipeline. my entity/token is

```
Machine_DS2302
```

Where the second part is `alphanumeric`.

What I have currently is

```
Machine_.*  MachineNumber
```

But, this annotates everything (this is being a wildcard). I would like to add the tag as `MachineNumber` based on the the **regex** in the second part i.e. if the second part after _ is a number, then assign it the said tag.

The regex pattern

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

But even

```
Machine_^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Does not work

How would such a pattern look like for the regexNER?

Comment: You need to remove the anchors - `Machine_[a-zA-Z0-9]*`, and perhaps, even capture it - `Machine_([a-zA-Z0-9]*)` if you need  `DS2302` value separately.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes it works. You may add this as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchors are redundant, they actually prevent the pattern from matching because `^` matches a string start location and `$` matches the string end location.

Since you need to have access to the part after `_`, you need to also capture, so use a capturing group:

```
Machine_([a-zA-Z0-9]*)
```

The `(...)` will create a submatch with the alphanumeric value.

Note that you might want to replace `*` with `+` if the alphanumeric part should consist of at least 1 char.

Comment: If it is Java regex flavor as [the docs suggest](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner.html), you might replace `[A-Za-z0-9]` with `\p{Alnum}` to match alphanumeric characters. Or, if there are Unicode letters to deal with, you may use `[\p{L}\p{M}0-9]`